# List function - determining positive/negative values and if they are greater/less than

Tags: python, list, sum

Okay so I am given the following question: Given a list of integers, L, write code to determine whether the sum of the positive integers in the list is
greater than the (absolute value of the) sum of the negative numbers in the list and print an appropriate
message.

And this is what I came up with for code, but it doesn't work it simply returns the input numbers within brackets ex input=-1,-2,4,5 output=(-1,-2,4,5)

```
def question(L):
   L = input()
   sumPositive = () #List where I will send the positive integers from "L" list
   sumNegative = () #List where I will send the negative integers from "L" list

   if x in L >= 0:
      append.x(sumPositive) #checks if the number is equal to or greater than 0, if so add it to          "sumPositive" list
  elif:
      append.x(sumNegative) #if not add it to "sumNegative" list

if sum(sumPositive) > abs(sum(sumNegative)):
   print "The sum of positive numbers is greater than the absolute value of negative numbers."
   elif: 
      sum(Positive) < abs(sum(sumNegative)):
         print "The sum of absolute value of negative numbers is greater than the sum of positive         numbers."
   else:
   print "They are equal."
```

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong or if I'm going about something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Did you even read about python `List` datastructure?

Comment: Where are you returning output?

Answer (score 1):

a much more pythonic solution :

```
def question(lst):
    sum_pos = sum(x for x in lst if x >0)
    sum_neg = sum(abs(x) for x in lst if x<0)

    if sum_pos > sum_neg:
        print "The sum of positive numbers is greater than the absolute value of negative numbers."
    elif sum_pos < sum_neg:
        print "The sum of absolute value of negative numbers is greater than the sum of positive numbers."
    else:
        print "They are equal."

question([1,-1,-2,-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

`()` creates an empty tuple, not a list. `append()` is a list method, e.g. `foo.append(bar)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def question(L):

   sumPositive = [] #List where I will send the positive integers from "L" list
   sumNegative = [] #List where I will send the negative integers from "L" list

   for x in L:
       if x>0:
           sumPositive.append(x)
       else :
           sumNegative.append(x) #if not add it to "sumNegative" list

   if sum(sumPositive) > abs(sum(sumNegative)):
       print "The sum of positive numbers is greater than the absolute value of negative numbers."
   elif sum(sumPositive) < abs(sum(sumNegative)):
         print "The sum of absolute value of negative numbers is greater than the sum of positive         numbers."
   else:
        print "They are equal."

question([1,-1,-2,-2])
```

You can apppend in a list. You have created a tuple. and you have to use a for loop to iterate through the input list. I could not understand why you used a if condition.

In python `tuples are immutable`. You cannot change them. You can concatnate tuples. But I am sure that is not required in here. A list would suffice.

Comment: So if I had just used a for loop and set the lists to [] rather than () it would have worked

Comment: It would be better if you read this first.  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: I will read that now, and one more thing if I wanted to go about changing it so that the input is a list of numbers ex: X,Y,Z.. etc where each of those is a user supplied input. Would I just set L = input() and call L in the end with question([L])?

Comment: You dont call L. You call a function.

Comment: `L= map(int, raw_input("enter numbers separated by space").split())` 
question(L)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def question(x):
...    s1=sum([i for i in x if i>0])
...    s2=sum([abs(i) for i in x if i<0])
...    if s1>s2:
...       print "The sum of positive numbers is greater than the absolute value of negative numbers."
...    elif s1<s2:
...       print "The sum of absolute value of negative numbers is greater than the sum of positive numbers."
...    else:
...       print "They are equal."
... 
>>> lst = [1,2,3,-1,-5,-7,3,-4,5,-6]
>>> question(lst)
The sum of absolute value of negative numbers is greater than the sum of positive numbers.
>>> lst=[-1,-2,3,2,3]
>>> question(lst)
The sum of positive numbers is greater than the absolute value of negative numbers.
>>> lst=[-2,-3,-3,3,2,3]
>>> question(lst)
They are equal.
```